# Issue with Session Helper in another Helper

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am trying to use the Session Helper in another Helper.

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

/**
 * @alias Mathjax Class for helper
 * @description This class is to define helper in CakePHP. 
 */
class MathjaxHelper extends AppHelper{
    var $helpers = array ('Html', 'Form', 'Session'); 

    var $status = false;

    /*
     * Constructor of the class.
     */
    function __construct(){
            $this->setStatus();
    }

    function create(){
            return $this->status;
    }

    /*
     * mantain the status that the js files are loaded already
     * 
     * When we call help multiple time it may happen that same js files loaded with next helper call.
     * 
     */
     private function setStatus(){
            $this->status = $this->Session->read('Mathjax.status');
            if( $this->Session->check('Mathjax.status') ){
                    $this->status = $this->Session->read('Mathjax.status');
            } else {
                    $this->Session->write('Mathjax.count', $status);
            }
    }
}
```

But here the Session Helper is not available to use. CakePHP throws an error as:

```
Error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object
File: /var/www/PHP/folder/app/View/Helper/MathjaxHelper.php
Line: 31
```

Can anyone help me? How could I use the Session Helper in another Helper?

Comment: After looking at your code a little this looks like you only want to avoid loading the same js file multiple times - you should ask _that_ question (as a new question) as this helper is not the best solution for that - or a "good" one.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My motto is to identify js load. But I am going to call this helper in single page multiple times. For each call I am going to load the necessary JS files. But every time loading the same files is not correct. I reached to this question. Can you please direct the proper way out for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Good children call their parents

This:

```
function __construct(){
    $this->setStatus();
}
```

Means that your helper inherits none of [the base code for a helper](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L173-L182), whenever overriding a method, it's a good idea to call the parent method unless there's a specific reason not to.

This method also has a different method signature.

Therefore, change it to:

```
function __construct(View $View, $settings = array()) {
    parent::__construct($View, $settings);
    $this->setStatus();
}
```

To use as written, or consider using [beforeRender](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L810-L819) and not the constructor for your bespoke code.

### SessionHelper::write does not exist

Note that [the Session helper has no write method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/SessionHelper.php) - to write to the session you'll need to use [the `CakeSession` interface](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data).

Comment: I have tried your code but now it throw error as:

Warning (512): Method SessionHelper::write does not exist [CORE/Cake/View/Helper.php, line 191]

Can you please look over it?

Comment: well, no =). I already pointed out that won't work, and what to do to make it work.